# Regex param from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you help me please to get some param from an URL.

Url should be the form : `http.www.lolilol.com/gallery/Param1/Param2/Param3/`

I need to get `Param1`, `Param2` and `Param3`.

Comment: `http.www`??? not `http://www`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution :

```
var params = document.location.pathname.split('/').slice(2);
```

This gives you the array `["Param1", "Param2", "Param3"]`

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be `http://www\.lolilol\.com/gallery/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/` assuming you meant `http://www.lolilol.com/gallery/Param1/Param2/Param3/`